# Spark - Getting Type mismatch when assigning a string label to null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset with a stringType column which contains nulls. I wanted to change each row with a null value with a string. I was trying the following:

```
val renameDF = DF
.withColumn("code", when($"code".isNull,lit("NON")).otherwise($"code"))
```

But I am getting the following exception:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN
>   (del.`code` IS NULL) THEN 'NON' ELSE del.`code` END' due to
>   data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type
>   or coercible to a common type;

How can I make the string a column type compatible with `$"code"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird, I just tried this snippet :

```
val df = Seq("yoyo","yaya",null).toDF("code")
df.withColumn("code", when($"code".isNull,lit("NON")).otherwise($"code")).show
```

And this is working fine, can you share your spark version. And did you import the spark implicits ? Are you sure your column is StringTyped ?

Comment: You were right, actually it was an array of string. Do you know by change how to convert that lit("NON") in an array with just that string inside?

Comment: Use inbuilt function `array(lit("NON"))`